# Can two JVM's share a volatile variable?

Tags: java, caching, jvm, volatile

I read somewhere in SO that volatile variable is used from the cache of the system(stored in hardware cache). But if it is in the system's cache then is it possible that another JVM can change that volatile variable ?
If yes, how it will access that particular volatile variable?

Comment: Short of getting into "native" code, a Java app cannot access ANYTHING outside of its assigned storage segments (stack & heap).  The spec doesn't say anything about shared storage because the concept, from the Java standpoint, simply does not exist.

Comment: (*All* data in *all* programs (with a few very tiny exceptions) is "stored in hardware cache" at one point or another.  In fact, the significant thing about *volatile* is that, in essence, cache is *bypassed* to access a *volatile*.)

Comment: (You might want to spend 30 minutes or so with Google, researching what "cache" really is.)

Comment: thanks hot licks , i really need to revisit my OS concepts and Cache concepts too..

Comment: Same was asked by an interviewer to me. I was not having any answer for this.